# Getting the amount of elements in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have been looking up about LocalStorage, however I cannot seem to find an answer to my question.

So basically, I need to be able to find the amount of items stored in a users LocalStorage. Is there any dedicated function in the HTML5 LocalStorage API?

Regards,
Jack Hunt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.localStorage` actually returns a `Storage` object which has a `.length` parameter, so this should work:

`window.localStorage.length`

Edit --

I'm *assuming* this returns the amount of items stored for a given domain.  If you were building a browser plugin and wanted to access the amount of items for all domains it would likely be something else entirely.